# Vlan over ipsec VPN?

Tags: vpn

I have a VPN over ipsec established between 2 sites (site 1 and site 2) with Cisco 871.

Please see my network diagram : http://img806.imageshack.us/img806/9821/img007.jpg

I created vlan on my 3com switches.
Now, I would like to keep VLAN's between site 1 and site 2.

If I am vlan1/site1, after the VPN, I will be always in the vlan1/site2 and vlan2/site1 -> vlan2/site2.

Is it possible ?

I'm looking for something like that on google, and I find : "dot1q tunneling"

Comment: You can encapsulate VLANs inside traffic destined for another VLAN. The keyword here is QinQ.  But I'm not sure that's what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, VLANs are a concept that is local to a switch. In consequence the VLANs on site1 are always completely independent from the VLANs on site2.

Comment: +1. VLAN are ETHERNET level, which has no correspondence in IP - so they do not go over VPN.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is still possible with OpenVPN, if you use TAP connectivity.